# Fetching the data from hidden urls

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a website which has few data present in it , some data are in the pagination format.
But wen i try to fetch the HTML data of the url using view-source, the pagination data is not found in it. and wen i go to the second column of the pagination data the url is also nt changed.

My question:-

```
 How to fetch the hidden data or data that is bought by Javascript into the HTML format
```

Hope u all gt my question. Thanks in advance

Updated Part:-

I am basically trying to scrape the data , so wen i enter the url and try to scrape the data , i wont get the required data, because the data is not present in the HTML format, it is bought by Javascript/JQuery

My Simple Code:-

```
 $html = file_get_html(myurl);
 print $html;
 //Wen i print i wont get the data that is fetched by Javascript,
```

My doubt:-

```
How to fetch the data from Java script ???
```

Comment: Open the network tab on Chrome's debugger, then reload the page - voila! The url of all files loaded by the page.

Comment: The url remains the same its nt at all changing, hence the problem. I tried to fetch the url from firebug , But no use :(

Comment: Yeah, I know the url in the browser's address bar stays the same. That's why I told you to look at the network tab. As an exercise, load the main page of S.O. Now, open the dev tools, switch to the network tab. There should be a msg saying "! No requests captured..." etc. Now, hover your cursor over any of the tags for any of the questions you see - keep watching the network tab. After a second or so, you'll see a request for something like "subscriber-info?_=1368858815822" (javascript tag) - The address bar still says "stackoverflow.com" - i.e then ajax Url has been captured.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get one of the web developer tools to be able to view that live (what I think you're asking). Try out either [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome Dev tools to see the Dom after javascript has had it's way with it.

If you are talking about doing it in code then again get one of the developer tools and that will give you the insight into the resultant dom that you will need.

Comment: But they need to get that data via their code, not just in browser

Comment: going to be hard to do if you're relying on "view source" to get the lay of the land

Answer (score -1):

You need something like [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/), something to actually evaluate the javascript on the page and the proceed to pragmatically fetch the content, or figure from where does the javascript is fetching the data probably you can just make a call and fetch some json, use the developer tools of any browser to see all the requests.